# Reason why if I change common.d.ts ionic serve runs properly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, dependencies, ionic-cli

When I execute *ionic serve*, I have this error:

> [app-scripts] [15:04:28]  transpile started ...
>   [app-scripts] [15:04:42]  typescript: ...aceIcaro_5_3B/dev-app/app/node_modules/@ionic-native/core/decorators/common.d.ts, line: 10 
>   [app-scripts]             Cannot find name 'unknown'.
>   [app-scripts]        L9:  export declare function wrapPromise(pluginObj: any, methodName: string, args: any[], opts?: CordovaOptions): Promise;
>   [app-scripts]       L11:   * Checks if plugin/cordova is available

I have read that if I change unknown for any at line 10 of common.d.ts at @ionic-native/core/decorators, the error disappears. It's true, but I want to know the reason.

My dependencies at package.json are:

> "dependencies": {
>       "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
>       "@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
>       "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11",
>       "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
>       "@angular/core": "^5.2.11",
>       "@angular/forms": "^5.2.11",
>       "@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
>       "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.11",
>       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.11",
>       "@angular/router": "^5.2.11",
>       "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^1.2.0",
>       "@ionic-native/app-version": "5.14.0",
>       "@ionic-native/core": "5.14.0",
>       "@ionic-native/date-picker": "5.14.0",
>       "@ionic-native/file": "^5.14.0",
>       "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.14.0",
>       "@ionic-native/globalization": "5.14.0",
>       "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "5.14.0",
>       "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "5.14.0",
>       "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.14.0",
>       "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.14.0",
>       "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
>       "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
>       "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
>       "@types/lodash": "4.14.118",
>       "cordova": "^9.0.0",
>       "cordova-android": "8.1.0",
>       "cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
>       "cordova-ios": "5.0.1",
>       "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
>       "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "^0.9.3",
>       "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
>       "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
>       "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^2.2.1",
>       "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.11.0",
>       "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.1.0",
>       "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
>       "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.2",
>       "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
>       "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git",
>       "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
>       "ionic-angular": "^3.9.8",
>       "ionic-tooltips": "^2.1.1",
>       "ionic2-super-tabs": "^4.3.1",
>       "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
>       "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
>       "lodash": "4.17.11",
>       "moment": "^2.24.0",
>       "ngx-permissions": "^4.1.0",
>       "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
>       "run": "1.4.0",
>       "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
>       "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
>       "zone.js": "0.8.26"
>     },
>     "devDependencies": {
>       "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.2",
>       "@ionic/lab": "1.0.6",
>       "typescript": "2.8.3"
>     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I made these changes because in a device with iOS13 as OS I can't visualize the native calendar and clock.

So I can say that I have two solutions.

The problem with calendar and clock is due to the new dark mode so I force the devices with iOS to use light mode with my app.

The problem with dependecies is more complicated. I came back to a previous version, so all works fine. If I want to update my dependecies, I must replace “ionic-angular” for “@ionic/angular”, update typescript, all the @angular/* stuff needs to join @angular/core and “ionic2-super-tabs” can generate problems. So it's better to generate a new project and migrate my code.